# grid-template-areas not working with long text

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm sure I am just using it wrong, but here is my code:

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: myArea;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'myArea myArea . . .';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The grid-template-areas Property</h1>

<p>You can use the <em>grid-template-areas</em> property to set up a grid layout.</p>

<p>Item1, is called "myArea" and will take up the place of two columns (out of five):</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <div>div with some very long text in it</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
  <div class="item9">9</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/danielhoang/w4ydmf3k/1/

Which means item1 should take up 40% of space, but in the code, it takes up over half the space.

If I change item1 to have a short amount of text, then it works fine.

Is there a way to make item1 still 40% even with long text?

Comment: I think you still need to set the `grid-template-columns` property. Take a look at this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) from MDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place grid areas using `grid-template-areas`, but don't also define `grid-template-columns`, the latter keeps the default value of `auto` for each column. That means that the columns will be sized based on the length of the content, which is what you're seeing.

Add this to your grid container:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr)
```

Now all space will be distributed evenly in the row.